# Using django-haystack, how do I perform a search with only partial terms?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I've got a Haystack/xapian search index for `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. The template is simply

```
{{object.get_full_name}}
```

as I intend for a user to type in a name and be able to search for it.

My issue is this: if I search, say, `Sri` (my full first name) I come up with a result for the user object pertaining to my name. However, if I search `Sri Ragh` - that is, my full name, and part of my last name, I get no results.

How can I set Haystack up so that I can get the appropriate results for partial queries?
(I essentially want it to search `*Sri Ragh*`, but I don't know if wildcards would actually do the trick, or how to implement them).

This is my search query:

```
results = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='Sri Ragh')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use to have a similar problem, as workaround or maybe a Fix you can change the query lookup

```
results = SearchQuerySet().filter(content__startswith='Sri Ragh')
```

The issue is that django-haystack doesn't implement all lingos from search engines. Of course you can do this.

```
results = SearchQuerySet().raw_search('READ THE SEARCH ENGINE QUERY SYNTAX FOR GET WILDCARD LOOKUPS')
```

As Django-haystack says, this is not portable.

Comment: Since I'm using the default SearchView class, I ended up using your __startswith solution by subclasing the ModelSearchForm and passing that to SearchView's constructor in urls.py.

Thank you for your help. I'll award you the bounty as soon as I can.

Answer (score -1):

You can use icontains or startswith.

Be careful with this one, if a query is for example 'r', this will bring you all 'Model' entities that have a 'r' in its content.

```
Model.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)

Model.objects.filter(content__startswith=query)
```

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: This is how you'd do a full-text database search, and doesn't use the search engine.